# Como funciona a instância de declaração de Table em Lua?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, lua, construtor

Em orientação a objetos, geralmente se cria a classe primeiro e depois se instancia a mesma.

Exemplo PHP:

```
class Test{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // inicia as parada aqui
    }
}

$test = new Test;
```

Porém no `Lua` parece me sempre que uma *table* é atribuída a variável através do `{}` e, em seguida, são criados métodos e propriedades.

- Existe construtor e instância em relação às *table* de Lua?
- Como se dá uma declaração de um método (ou função, não sei como a linguagem chama) de uma *table*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não tem o construtor formalmente. É possível criar uma função que seja um construtor para aquele objeto. É algo bem manual. Os métodos são criados como funções com "sobrenome". Um exemplo:

```
local MyClass = {}
MyClass.__index = MyClass    
function MyClass.new(init)
    local self = setmetatable({}, MyClass)
    self.value = init
    return self
end

function MyClass.set_value(self, newval)
  self.value = newval
end

function MyClass.get_value(self)
  return self.value
end

local i = MyClass.new(5)
print(i:get_value())
i:set_value(6)
print(i:get_value())
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/TableDeclaration.lua).

[Fonte](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientationTutorial).

Note que os nomes dos métodos são convenções apenas.

[Informação complementar](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ClassesAsConstructorClosures).

Comment: Então foi daí que eu vi o tal do método `:new`

Answer (score 4):

Uma coisa importante a se lembrar é que Lua **não** é orientada a objetos. Não existem classes propriamente ditas.

Lua funciona mais como a "orientação a objetos" do JavaScript (versões mais antigas dele, pelo menos), onde você mexia no ".prototype" do objeto.

Mas Lua é flexível ao ponto de poder "simular" orientação a objetos com algumas de suas construções.

Você pode começar definindo a sua "classe" (que, lembre-se, é um objeto mesmo. Não existem classes).

```lua
local Quadrado = {}
Quadrado.__index = Quadrado
```

A primeira linha simplesmente cria uma tabela vazia. Depois vamos colocar uns atributos e métodos nela. O importante aqui é a segunda linha. O `__index` passa todas as indexações (`Classe[x]`, `Classe.x`) para a própria tabela. Isso vai fazer sentido no próximo bloco de código.

Agora, vamos definir um construtor:

```lua
function Quadrado:novoQuadrado(tamanhoLado)
    return setmetatable({lado = tamanhoLado}, Quadrado)
end
```

A mágica é feita no `setmetatable`. Observe que estou retornando uma nova tabela, com um atributo *lado* (`{lado = tamanhoLado}`, e passando minha definição de *Quadrado* como a metatable dele.

Uma *metatable* é uma forma de alterar o comportamento de uma tabela. Um bom exemplo disso, é definir duas tabelas, `a` e `b`, e tentar somá-las `a + b`. Lua não sabe fazer isso, mas ela vai olhar nessas metatables das tabelas. Se alguma delas tiver um método no índice `__add`, Lua vai usar esse método para fazer a soma (algo como `a:__add(b)`).

Lembra do `__index` que mudamos lá em cima? É o mesmo esquema. Estamos mandando nosso Quadrado ir procurar indexações no próprio Quadrado. Quando se usarmos um `Quadrado.area`, que definiremos daqui a pouco, Lua vai procurar esse índice (ou atributo, ou campo) na tabela `Quadrado`, e encontrar `Quadrado.area`. Isso não faz sentido? Mas lembra que passamos o Quadrado como metatable? Então todos os objetos que criarmos usarão Quadrado como metatable, e vão procurar suas indexações da mesma forma (`Quadrado.area`). Não sei se deu pra entender o que quero dizer :(

Para definir um método, podemos usar a seguinte sintaxe:

```lua
function Quadrado:area()
  return self.lado * self.lado
end
```

Essa sintaxe `Quadrado:area` é só *syntatic sugar* para

```lua
function Quadrado.area(self)
```

Agora é só usar a nossa "classe":

```lua
local q = Quadrado:novoQuadrado(10)
print(q:area()) -- 100
```

O `q:area` é *syntatic sugar* para `q.area(q)` (lembra que alteramos a metatable? Isso está usando o area do Quadrado). Ainda não sei se deu pra entender, mas é isso.

Então, respondendo suas perguntas:

- Não, não existe um construtor, porque não existe uma classe. O que existe é a função que nós convencionamos como construtor (`Quadrado:novoQuadrado`).
- O método é declarado com a alteração na metatable.
- É importante notar que estamos usando dois "objetos" (duas tabelas, `Quadrado` e `q`), e não uma classe e um objeto.

Claro, faz tempo que não estudo Lua, e não sei se tem evoluções nesse esquema. Mas na minha época era assim.